# Regexp PHP PRCE trouble

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

In a string I have many HTML elements and one of them is input that should be parsed.

```
<input name="generate" value="52FadA=" type="hidden">
```

I have made the regexp but it doesn't work. May be escape characters, it's not clear :(

```
preg_match_all('/input[\s](?:(?:name\="generate"[\s]value\="(.*)")|(?:value\="(.*)"[\s]name\="generate"))[\s]/i',$html,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

What is wrong ?

Also will be very grateful for help to do it more universal e.g. in the case of random order of attributes.

Thanks, Oleg.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML, use an HTML parser instead.

Comment: `but it doesn't work` isn't very useful.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't** parse html with regexes. Use `DOMDocument::loadHTML($string)` and then use DOM or XPath methods to query data. `DOMDocument::loadHTML()` will gracefully parse document fragments.

In your example it might look like:

```
$str = '<input name="generate" value="52FadA=" type="hidden">';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);

$value = $doc->getElementsByNodeName('input')->item(0)->getAttribute('value');
```

Comment: But what if dom structure will change? :(

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem if you are using `getElementsByTagName()` as shown. Btw it would be harder to maintain regexes when the DOM changes. That's one of the reasons why it is considered bad practice

Comment: What is wrong ?

    $dom = new DOMDocument(5,'UTF-8');
    $dom->loadHTMLFile($this->auth_url);
    $token = null;
    $inputs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input');
    /** @var $input DOMElement */
    foreach($inputs as $input) {
        print_r( $input , true);
    }

Comment: `print_r()` will not work as you might expect on `DOMElement` as attributes or childs aren't local properties of `DOMElement` but `DOMElement` provides methods to access them. Use `echo $input->getAttribute($ATTR_NAME);`